# How to remove xticks and yticks from all axes?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axes, multiple-axes

I have three axes in figure and I want to remove `xtick` and `ytick` from all of them.
I wrote below code but it works just on current axes, not all of them:

```
set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[]);
```

How to remove `xticks` and `yticks` from all axes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a more general solution inspired by @Luis Mendo's answer, use `findobj` to get the axes. This will avoid getting all children of the parent figure which could include "non-axes" elements:

```
set( findobj( gcf, 'Type', 'axes' ), 'XTick', [], 'YTick', [] );
```

Comment: Good point, there may be other objects in addition to axes. Way to go

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
set(get(gcf,'Children'),'Xtick',[],'Ytick',[]);
```